# Open wireless settings from app

Tags: android, settings, wireless

I want to open the Settings-> Wireless & networks directly from my application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 89):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Or perhaps startActivityForResult. Your call. 
You can open different settings by checking the constants in [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Comment: Question : How can we open "Input Languages" Activity like this ?

Comment: you can use also this for direct data enable check box.. Tested..on samsung..

startActivity(new Intent(
      android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));

Comment: Using this get's you straight to WIFI settings for anyone who just wanted that.    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

Answer (score 17):

You can access the WiFi settings directly using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
startActivity(intent);
```

The above did not work on Android 3.0, so I ended up using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Works on Android 4.0.3, but not on 3.0. I ended up using something even simpler. See above.

Answer (score 11):

That code works for me.

`startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));`

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to call wireless and networks directly from your application.

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following Function For Open WI_FI Settings

```
private void openWifi() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried solutions above and it give me error that if you want to open external open you should flag that intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

 here is my solution in `kotlin`

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(getApplication(), intent, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, kotlin in 2022.

```
 val context = LocalContext.current

 fun onEnableConnection() {
     startActivity(context, Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), null)   }
```