# Displaying Desired Settings Screen on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application, certain tasks require a network connection of some kind (either wifi or cellular will do).  In MyActivity, I have a check on `onResume()` to check the network state, and if there is no connection, I would like to display the network settings screen:

```
private void showConnectionSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName( "com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings" );

    intent.setComponent( cn );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

    this.getBaseContext().startActivity( intent );
}
```

Yet this brings me the mobile network screen, when I would like to show `Wireless and Network Settings` screen where the user can pick their connection type.

Comment: "if there is no connection, *I want to* display the network settings screen"? Otherwards I don't know what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Open settings from app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454416/android-open-settings-from-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but might help someone. The best way to achieve this is :

- for showing general connectivity settings,

  `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);`
- for showing Mobile network connection settings

  `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS), 0);`
- for showing Wifi settings

  `startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);`

Answer (score 4):

In all honesty if they don't have coverage their only option is to use wifi.

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This just shows a dialog "searching."  This is more a matter of displaying the proper settings screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for showing up wireless and network settings.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```